# Calculating / Faking Line Height Changes in UILabel

Tags: ios, uilabel

I've discovered its impossible to modify the line height in a UILabel. Bummer. Also - it seems that the custom fonts I've chosen for use do not use their own default line heights when used with a UILable.

So - has anyone figured out an alternative? Is calculating individual lines and creating new UILabels for each line the only solution?

This is concerning dynamic text used in a UILabel with no manual linebreaks added and word wrap on btw.

Comment: You might want to look into Core Text if you want to have more control over text rendering (although it can look a little intimidating at first).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've recently written a class which uses CoreText to draw text with custom line height. It works almost like UILabel. Feel free to use it https://github.com/Tuszy/MTLabel

Comment: I have strange things happening when I use your class - specifically premature linebreaks. Any clue as to what's going on?

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative to using a UILabel, you might want to consider using a non-editable UITextField as a pseudo-label.

Answer (score -1):

You could use this if you're developing for iOS >= 6.0

```
NSInteger strLength = [myString length];
NSMutableParagraphStyle *style = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
[style setLineSpacing:24];
[attString addAttribute:NSParagraphStyleAttributeName
                  value:style
                  range:NSMakeRange(0, strLength)];
```